# Finding cell width of Raster using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro

I've been trying to find the cell size, or height/width/mean, of a cell by utilizing arcpy in the Python Window in ArcGIS Pro version 2.3.3., I run the following code:

```
import arcpy
env = arcpy.env
env.workspace = "D:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\pr\pen"
raster = "D:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\pr\pen\LandsatHMB201707"
description = arcpy.Describe(raster)
arcpy.env.Describe("D:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\pr\pen\LandsatHMB201707").meanCellHeight
```

I've looked into the raster properties here
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/raster-band-properties.htm

and the error code I get is:

> AttributeError: DescribeData: Method meanCellWidth does not exist

Answer (score 3):

You are calling Describe function again using `arcpy.env.Describe` which does not seem to be correct. Although you already used `arcpy.Describe()` which is the correct one. you did not use it.

Here is a working code, you can adjust your code based on it:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\Landsat_Test"
raster = "TestClassClip.tif"
desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
cellsize = 'Hight = {0}, Width = {1}'.format(desc.meanCellHeight,desc.meanCellWidth)
print (cellsize)
```

Output:

```
Hight = 30.0, Width = 30.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Ahmad, unfortunately it did not work. However I talked to a classmate and figured out what the problem was:

`
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"D:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\pr\pen\LandsatHMB201707"
describe = arcpy.Describe("LandsatHMB201707.tif\Band_1")
Cell_Size = describe.meanCellWidth
print(Cell_Size)
`

Was the correct code. Have to specify the specific band due to file having numerous bands.

Comment: @MichaelBreidert You are welcome. Glad you you could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"D:\Fall 2019\GEOG 625\pr\pen\LandsatHMB201707"
describe = arcpy.Describe("LandsatHMB201707.tif\Band_1")
Cell_Size = describe.meanCellWidth
print(Cell_Size)
```

Figured it out with a classmate, thank you for the help Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
import arcpy
my_raster = arcpy.Raster('/my_raster.tif')
cellsize = my_raster.meanCellHeight, my_raster.meanCellWidth
```